# How to query for substring with ILIKE in SQLx?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

How can I bind to a query so that `WHERE ... ILIKE '%$1%'` works? I am using the Rust SQLx crate with Postgres. I haven't found a solution in the library documentation.

Here is my code:

```
const QUERY_SELECT_COUNTRY_BY_COUNTRY_NAME: &str = "SELECT * FROM dictionary_country WHERE name_en ILIKE '%$1%' ";

pub async fn get_country_list_by_country_name(tx: &mut Transaction<'static, Postgres>, country_name: &str) -> Result<Vec<CountryModel>, AppGenericError> {
    info!("get_country_list_by_country_name country_name = {}", &country_name);

    match sqlx::query(QUERY_SELECT_COUNTRY_BY_COUNTRY_NAME)
        .bind("Rus")
        .map(|row: PgRow| CountryModel::from(row))
        .fetch_all(&mut *tx)
        .await
    {
        Ok(data) => Ok(data),
        Err(err) => Err(AppRepositoryError::general_error(err.to_string()))
    }
}
```

I expected to see 1 result row.

Comment: Have you tried putting the wrapping `%` in the bind instead?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the wrapping `%` in the bind instead:

```rust
const QUERY_SELECT_COUNTRY_BY_COUNTRY_NAME: &str = "SELECT * FROM dictionary_country WHERE name_en ILIKE $1 ";

pub async fn get_country_list_by_country_name(tx: &mut Transaction<'static, Postgres>, country_name: &str) -> Result<Vec<CountryModel>, AppGenericError> {
    info!("get_country_list_by_country_name country_name = {}", &country_name);

    match sqlx::query(QUERY_SELECT_COUNTRY_BY_COUNTRY_NAME)
        .bind(format!("%{}%", "Rus"))
        .map(|row: PgRow| CountryModel::from(row))
        .fetch_all(&mut *tx)
        .await
    {
        Ok(data) => Ok(data),
        Err(err) => Err(AppRepositoryError::general_error(err.to_string()))
    }
}
```